# Loss of Formatting when writing json file in python

Tags: python, json

I am getting a json response from an API.

```
json_response = response.json()

json_response

 [{'roll_no': 9091,
  'name': 'Akash Deep'},
 {'roll_no': 9090,
  'name': 'Jay Deep'}]
```

Above is the response received. I wish to write this to a json like this:

```
{
  "class": [
   {
    'roll_no': 9091,
    'name': 'Akash Deep'
    },
   {
  'roll_no': 9090,
  'name': 'Jay Deep'
  }]
}
```

This is what I did:

```
new_class = {"class":json_response}

with open("new_class.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(new_class , fp)
```

This is what I get:

```
{"class": [{'roll_no': 9091, 'name': 'Akash Deep'}, {'roll_no': 9090, 'name': 'Jay Deep'}]}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json.dump(new_class, indent=4, sort_keys=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this use dumps instead of dump with indent & sort ,

```
import json

data =  [{'roll_no': 9091,
  'name': 'Akash Deep'},
 {'roll_no': 9090,
  'name': 'Jay Deep'}]

newdata = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)


print(newdata)
```

Will give

```
[
    {
        "name": "Akash Deep",
        "roll_no": 9091
    },
    {
        "name": "Jay Deep",
        "roll_no": 9090
    }
]
```